# How to install a reoccurring timer function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer, thread-sleep, c++-chrono

Is there a simple way to install a regularly occurring timer function with C++/stdlib? I would like to get rid of the loop:

```
using namespace std::chrono; // literal suffixes
auto tNext = steady_clock::now();
while (<condition>) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(tNext);
    tNext = tNext + 100ms; 
    ...
```

That function will run in its own thread.

Comment: Do you mean you want the timer to work asynchronously, while the program does other stuff? Then you should put the timed process inside it's own thread.

Comment: @JasonLang yes of course, in its own thread

Comment: Do you mean you want something along the lines of `ping(100ms, callback)`?

Comment: What about a conditional variable or a mutex?

Comment: What does a cv or mutex have to do with timing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you want is this

```
int i = 10;
auto pred = [i]() mutable {return i--;};
auto print = []{cout << "." << endl;};

timer t{500ms};
t.push({print, pred});  //asynchronously prints '.' 10 times within 5s

//do anything else
```

Assuming performance is not critical and the timer is not often updated, the following should provide ample functionality.

```
#include<functional>
#include<vector>
#include<thread>
#include<utility>
#include<chrono>
#include<mutex>
#include<atomic>

class timer final
{
public:
    using microseconds = std::chrono::microseconds;

    using predicate = std::function<bool ()>;
    using callback = std::function<void ()>;
    using job = std::pair<callback, predicate>;

    explicit timer(microseconds t) : done{false}, period{t}
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx);

        worker = std::thread([this]{
            auto t = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            while(!done.load())
            {
                std::this_thread::sleep_until(t);
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
                t += period;
                for(auto it = jobs.begin(); it != jobs.end();)
                {
                    if(it->second())
                        it++->first();
                    else
                        it = jobs.erase(it);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    ~timer()
    {
        done.store(true);
        worker.join();
    }

    void set_period(microseconds t)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        period = t;
    }
    void push(const callback& c)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        jobs.emplace_back(c, []{return true;});
    }
    void push(const job& j)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        jobs.push_back(j);
    }

private:
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::atomic_bool done;
    std::thread worker;

    std::vector<job> jobs;
    microseconds period;
};
```

`timer` calls previously pushed `callback`s periodically, and when `predicate` evaluates to `false`, deletes the `callback` from the `timer`. The `timer` object has its own lifetime and its worker thread will only live as long as it is alive.

The reason you would want to have multiple `job`s in a single `timer` is so that they would be called together, using only one thread and be in sync with each other.

Don't worry about the `mutex` unless you are planning to update the timer >10,000 times a second, have a period of <1ms or have very time-consuming `callback`s.

Comment: Yes, that's a beautiful solution, beyond what I asked for, very useful in practice. Small question, because I am not very versed with atomics. Could you use an `atomic_flag` instead of `atomic_bool`? I hear its the only atomic with lock-free guarantee on all systems.

Comment: @towi you can make it work but it does get a bit clunky. Do note two things though: first, lockless  basically doesn't matter at all here. Second, even if it is not guaranteed by the standard, it is most definitely lockless in practice.