# Cocos2dx How to Call a Function Every 5 Secs Without Schedule Selector?

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

How do I call a function every 5 seconds without schedule selector because I'm trying to pass an argument?

Comment: I kinda want to point out this is [doable with STL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43635665/4832499) with very little hassle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, you can use CallFunc created inside a function:

```
void HelloWorld::myFunc(int arg){
    CCLOG("myFunc: %d", arg);
}

void HelloWorld::repeatFunc(){
    auto sequence = Sequence::createWithTwoActions(DelayTime::create(5.0f), CallFunc::create([&](){myFunc(++arg); repeatFunc(); }));
    runAction(sequence);
}
```