# How to make Keyboard button to continuously call callback function when hold-pressed Cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

I would like to ask how to make a particular sprite to move when the keyboard button is pressed?

I have this following code:

```
keyBoardListener->onKeyPressed = [](EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, Event* event)
    {
        switch (keyCode)
        {
        case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_LEFT_ARROW:
        case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_A:
            xMovement--;
            break;
        case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_RIGHT_ARROW:
        case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_D:
            xMovement++;
            break;
        case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_UP_ARROW:
        case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_W:
            yMovement++;
            break;
        case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_DOWN_ARROW:
        case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_S:
            yMovement--;
            break;
        }
    };
```

The problem with this is that every time I pressed a button, it doesn’t perform this function again even though I hold-press a button.

Comment: You can create a separate thread to periodically check whether a key is pressed and update the sprite's location accordingly, or just create a transition to make sprite move continuously until the key is released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, add two methods to your scene class: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43842348/13785815)

```cpp
class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::Scene
{
    // ...
private:
    // For scheduling
    void scheduleMotions(); // schedule checks
    void checkMotions();    // does the check
};
```

`scheduleMotions()` should be like:

```cpp
void HelloWorld::scheduleMotions() {
    auto sequence = Sequence::createWithTwoActions(
        DelayTime::create(0.4f), 
        CallFunc::create([&]() { checkMotions(); scheduleMotions(); })
    );
    runAction(sequence);
}
```

Every time the timer expires, `checkMotions()` will run before the action is registered again. `checkMotions()` should contain the logic of checking key status and adjust the sprites' positions.

**Second**, call `scheduleMotions()` at the the end of `init()` method of your scene. This will trigger the call of `checkMotions()` every 400 ms (as is given in the code above).

**Third**, modify `keyBoardListener->onKeyPressed` and `keyBoardListener->onKeyReleased` callbacks so that every relevant key press/release event is recorded. You can use a map or an array to keep track of that. The information can be used in `checkMotions()`.